# Calling a div upon hover inside several layers of DIVS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a navbar that would show the div upon hover. I am familiar in calling the DIV if it's within the same DIV but I can't understand how to call the DIV if it's outside the original DIV and within layers of DIV.

I'm still practicing and am trying to understand how the navbar works on this website. How can I code this purely in CSS. https://www.onupkeep.com/

```css
body { 
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: gray;
}
ul, li, ol {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.logo {
 content: url("../img/logo.jpg");
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.d1navwrpr {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.navbar1 {
 width: 100%;
}

.logoimg {
 display: block;
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
}

.navbarmenu {
 width: 60%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.loginbts{
 width:270px;
 float: right;
 padding: 20px 0px 30px 0;
}

.login {
 display: block;
 color:black;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 float:left;
}
.signup {
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #ff3b30;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #ff3b30;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-radius: 45px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 float: left;
}

.pbold {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
 padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
}
.navbaroption {
 padding-left: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 z-index: 1; 
 top: 104;
}
.navbarmenu li a:hover .navbaroption{
 display: block;
}


.navbaroption li a:hover, .navbarmenu li a:hover {
 color: #ff3b30;
}

.option1 {
 float: left;
}

.option1 li {
 padding: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.navbaroption {
 display: noe;
 background-color: white;
}

.navbarmenu li a:hover {
 display: block;
}

.mpwrpr {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1navwrpr"><!--HeaderNav-->
 
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="logoimg">
 <img class="logo"></div>

 <div class="navbarmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a class="pbold">Platform</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Support</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Company</a></li>
 </ul></div>

  <div class="loginbts">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="mainpage.html" class="signup">Sign Up</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
 

 

 <div class="navbaroption">

   <div class="option1">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
   </ul></div>

   <div class="option1">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
   </ul></div>

   <div class="option1">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
   </ul></div>
  
   <div class="option1">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
   </ul></div>

  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Francis! Here at Stackoverflow, it's more helpful if you provided the current code that you have. Once you have done that, I can help you. What you're trying to do can be accomplished through jQuery, but I need to see what I'm working with. So please edit your post with a snippet (by clicking the <> icon) of your current code.

Comment: Hi Sorry. I just added them. I'm new to this so my codes maybe messy. Thanks,

Comment: On the site you gave as an example, the same div is shown regardless of which link you hover. Is that what you want?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Yes, It will show that div with all those links regardless what link is hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really figure out why you assigned a value of `position: absolute` to your "navbaroption" div, because it's causing problems.

However, I'll provide you with the code still, nonetheless.

Your CSS however does need some editing to properly place that navbar.

In the Snippet below, I have made it so that:

1. When you hover over your navbarmenu, it will display the navbaroption.
2. When you remove your mouse from this area, it will make the navbaroption disappear.

Problem: The fact that your navbar option has a value of `position: absolute` puts it above the navbarmenu, so when it shows, it goes through a constant loop of showing and hiding.

If you wish to have a fancy dropdown animation on the navbaroption or any further assistance, the CSS will need to be fixed up first, so that it can actually function properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbaroption").hide();
/* Beginning of Script */
    $(".navbarmenu").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".navbaroption").show();
    });
    $(".navbarmenu").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".navbaroption").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body { 
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: gray;
}
ul, li, ol {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.logo {
 content: url("logo.jpg");
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.d1navwrpr {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.navbar1 {
 width: 100%;
}

.logoimg {
 display: block;
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
}

.navbarmenu {
 width: 60%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.loginbts{
 width:270px;
 float: right;
 padding: 20px 0px 30px 0;
}

.login {
 display: block;
 color:black;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 float:left;
}
.signup {
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #ff3b30;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #ff3b30;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-radius: 45px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 float: left;
}

.pbold {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
 padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
}
.navbaroption {
 padding-left: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 z-index: 1; 
 top: 104;
}


.navbaroption li a:hover, .pbold:hover {
 color: #ff3b30;
}

.option {
 float: left;
}

.option li {
 padding: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.navbaroption {
 display: block;
 background-color: black;
}

.pbold:hover {
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="d1navwrpr"><!--HeaderNav-->
 
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="logoimg">
 <img class="logo"></div>

 <div class="navbarmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a class="pbold">Nav1</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Nav2</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Nav3</a></li>
  <li><a class="pbold">Nav4</a></li>
 </ul></div>

  <div class="loginbts">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="mainpage.html" class="signup">Sign Up</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
 

 

 <div class="navbaroption">

   <div class="option">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
   </ul></div>

   <div class="option">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
   </ul></div>

   <div class="option">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
   </ul></div>
  
   <div class="option">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option/a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option</a></li>
   </ul></div>

  
 </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: I have it absolute because I have another Div below the nav bar so it will appear on top of the div when it navbaroption appears.